# C: Ampersand operator applied to an array vs pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Let's say we have

```
int foo[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

`foo` would then be a pointer to the first element of the array.
We can do:

```
printf("%p", foo); // OUTPUT is some address 0xffffcc00
```

Now if we do:

```
printf("%p", &foo); // OUTPUT is the same address 0xffffcc00
```

Looking online, I see this particular syntax for `&<array-name>` takes the address of the entire array. This explains the two same values above, because the starting element's address is the same as the whole array's address.

But in general, my understanding is that `&` should take address of whatever is on its right. (i.e. in this case, **it "should" have taken the address of the pointer to the first element of the array**.)

So why isn't `&foo` taking the address of the pointer `foo`?
If this is an exception to the C language, is this the only exception, or are there other cases like this?

Comment: "why isn't &foo taking the address of the pointer foo" --> `foo` is not a pointer.  It is an array.  `&foo` is not "the address of the pointer to the first element of the array".  It is the address of the array.

Comment: Please [edit] your non-answer below as additional info into this question.

Comment: [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3)

Answer (score 4):

There is a common misconception that pointers and arrays are the same thing.  They are *not*, but they are related.

Your first example works:

```
printf("%p", foo);
```

Because in most contexts an array **decays** to a pointer to the first element of the array.

One of the situations where this is *not* the case is when an array is the operand of the address-of operator `&`.  This gives the address of the entire array, not just the first element (even though the values are the same).

This is detailed in section 6.3.2.1p3 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> Except  when  it  is  the  operand  of  the `sizeof` operator, the
>   `_Alignof` operator, or the unary `&` operator, or is a string 
>   literal  used  to  initialize  an  array, an expression  that  has
>   type "array of *type*" is converted to an expression with type
>   "pointer to *type*"  that  points to  the  initial  element  of  the 
>   array  object  and  is  not  an  lvalue.   If  the  array  object  has
>   register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: char foo[8] = {1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0};
char* soo = foo;
printf("%p\n", foo);
printf("%p\n", &foo);
printf("%p\n", soo);
printf("%p\n", &soo);

0xffffcc18
0xffffcc18
0xffffcc18
0xffffcc10

cool.

Comment: I found 6.5.3.2 of the standard "The operand of the unary & operator shall be ... **an lvalue** ...", which sounds like `&array` is not allowed, since `array` alone (i.e. without `[]`) is not an lvalue. Could you clarify please? I ask because I tried to make a convincing answer from that ... and did not dare... I was hoping for something like an explicit "`&array` is undefined."

Comment: @Yunnosch `array` by itself is an lvalue, although not a modifiable one.  The passage I quoted specifies when an array is converted from an lvalue to an rvalue which excludes the three operators mentioned.

Comment: Hmm "is an lvalue, although not a modifiable one" does not match my understanding of "lvalue". Not saying that your are wrong, could you link to the definition of lvalue, to allow me reading up?

Comment: @Yunnosch 6.3.2.1p1 defines a *modifiable lvalue*.  Basically it means something that can appear on the left side of an assignment, which a bare array can not.

Comment: OK, that debunks my (luckily unwritten) answer on arrays not being lvalues... Thank you very much. I just stumble about the non-obvious uses of "lvalue" in contrast to "modifiable lvalue". I could understand "normally modifiable lvalue under the effect of const". But that does not match arrays... Well, good enough for me. I have no language lawyer ambitions.

Comment: *an array decays to a pointer to the first element of the array*  Personally, I prefer, "an array decays to the address of the first element of the array (which is passed as a pointer in any function call)" . That's obviously longer, but IMO it's a lot more accurate as it captures the inability to assign to a bare array.

Comment: `(even though the values are the same)` Then how are they not the same thing?

Comment: @endolith The numeric values are the same but the types are not.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, Pointers used to access array elements in a alternative
        ease way.In Low level Programming, each and every variable has an
        address to allocate in memory. BTW, the array is also a variable
        name as like scalar variable.

Unlike Scalar Variables, Array variable has few things.,

- List(sequences) of elements allocated in subsequent memory address.
- So we can get all the elements by using first element address

FYI, Array Name == Address of the first element == Address of the array

> (foo == &foo == &foo[0])

So while you are trying to get elements by using this notation *foo, initially it points to* (&foo + 0) , so based on ith value you can access all the elements one by one.
Hope this Answer will helps.:)

Comment: `foo == &foo` is like saying `42 == 42.0`.  In both cases, the _values_ are equivalent, yet the _types_ differ.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using [this explanation](https://blogs.oracle.com/linux/the-ksplice-pointer-challenge-v2) about '*& basically means "the address-of operator"*' thesis. So, Arrays are not pointers! But an array can automatically "decay" into a pointer. Into `&foo[0]`, in your case. But `&foo` is a pointer to an array of four integers because of its type. To get PoC you need to check `ptype foo` vs `ptype &foo` under `GDB`.